# Azure Databricks High concurrency + Table access control + external hive metastore + ADLS pass through

Tags: external, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks, hive-metastore

Databricks high concurrency cluster with external hive meta store + ADLS passthrough + Table access control is no more supported ‍♂️

Any thoughts on how to achieve the below functionality

External hive meta store is needed since we migrated from HDInsight to Databricks.
With external hive meta store it is evident that there are many advantages (one of is we can migrate to any Hadoop cluster without worrying about metadata, that’s how we migrated from HDInsight to Databricks).

Table access control is needed to grant fine grained  access on the hive databases. My users need read on some , read write on some hive databases.

ADLS pass through is needed for the users to perform  read / write operations on the ADLS.(that’s where hive databases point to)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for answers on how to do this but, you cannot do this, at least not at this time.

Based on this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-passthrough#known-limitations
Passthrough and Table ACL are not supported
"
The powers granted by Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough could be used to bypass the fine-grained permissions of Table ACLs, while the extra restrictions of Table ACLs will constrain some of the power you get from Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough.
"
You need to drop at least one of these two.
There is also a problem between External Hive and High Concurrency features but that may be by passable.